# get data-attribute from option in Angular

Tags: angular

I have the following HTML which 2-way binds the `option` text to the `newNumber` instance variable.

```
 <select id="inputState" [(ngModel)]="newNumber" name="newNumber" class="form-control">
    <option data-value-x="192" data-value-y="108" selected="selected"> First</option>
    <option data-value-x="128" data-value-y="72">Second </option>
    <option data-value-x="108" data-value-y="108">Third </option>
    <option data-value-x="72"  data-value-y="72">Forth</option>
 </select>
```

I would like to access `data-value-x` and `data-value-y` for the selected option. This can I do that the Angular way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just bind the select to an object containing the values:

```
    <select name="point" [(ngModel)]="point">
      <option></option>
      <option [ngValue]="{x: 192, y: 108}">First</option>
      <option [ngValue]="{x: 128, y: 72}">Second</option>
    </select>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aeI920Ukaa8qJSoyE4xN?p=preview)

Of course, you should define your model in the code, not in the template. This allows selecting the first element of the array of points by default:

```
points = [
  {name: 'First', value: {x: 192, y: 108}},
  {name: 'Second', value: {x: 128, y: 72}}
];

point: {x: number; y: number;} = this.points[0].value;
```

And in the template:

```
    <select name="point" [(ngModel)]="point">
      <option *ngFor="let p of points" [ngValue]="p.value">{{ p.name }}</option>
    </select>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/eVW8G0YiQHPPEjKZYqRx?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. This works. Unfortunately it does not set the default option visible. Any idea how to make default option displayed. I mean, before you click anything, there should be an option already displayed. At the moment, it is  blank.

Comment: This indeed works perfectly. But I am even more confused. What I tried was setting `point`directly `point= {x:192, y:108}`. This does not make select element display a default value. But if I store the points in an array first, as you did, than it works. Why is that?

Comment: Because, in JavaScript, `{x:192, y:108} === {x:192, y:108}` is `false`. The selected point must be the exact same object as on of the options. Not a different object having the same properties.

Comment: gotcha. Thanks for your time:)